# wp_schedule_event and Daylight Savings

Tags: wordpress, cron, dst

So I ran into an issue on a website this morning that uses WP Cron. The code looks like this:

```
//Schedule the cron to run if not scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_check_cron_event' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( strtotime('tomorrow America/New_York') , 'daily', 'my_check_cron_event' );
}
```

The issue is pretty simple. That code works fine, essentially I want to run the function at midnight local time, every day. So when I first run the function - it gets the timestamp for midnight tomorrow - local time. And ever since - the functino has been running.

Now this weekend - because of daylight savings time, the function doesn't actually ever get RESCHEDULED - its just set to run every 24 hours. So the function started running at 11pm. Of course that's easy to fix - but will just break again. I can't really find any good posts on the topic - how would you deal with:

wp_schedule_event running daily when daylight savings time changes?

Just to preempt an obvious answers here: I can't run a proper cron - it needs to be done through wp. Our host simply doesn't support it, it sucks - but that's the client. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: So you need to schedule events based on how long daylight is present?

Comment: Did you configure UTC with new york timezone in wordpress settings(i think this itself will work)?, WP Cron works only when user visits. If no visits during the stipulated time then it won't run and if any user visit after the time, it will trigger immediately and set the next scheduled time so you won't expect result like server cron, hope you already aware?

Comment: I don't need to schedule it based on daylight, I need it to run at midnight LOCAL TIME regardless of daylight.

The timezone is properly configured - And I have a ping setup to hit the server at the right time to run this cron, I understand all that. The problem is that the cron ITSELF is scheduled to run every 24 hours - from when it is first set. That 24 hour countdown needs to CHANGE when the timezone changes - to continue running at midnight.

Answer (score 4):

So for anyone coming across this, I had to come back to this for a permanent solution today - as Daylight savings is about to change! The root issue here is that wp_schedule_event - accepts a parameter thats a number of seconds until the next run. That parameter is saved to the cron array - and it really doesn't care what timezone you're in. It just keeps running at that interval. In order to fix this - I had to switch to wp_schedule_single_event.

It seems counter-intuitive, because we want this to run on an interval. But the difference is - we NEED to recalculate the next timestamp to run at:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_check_cron_event' ) ) {
   wp_schedule_single_event( strtotime('tomorrow America/New_York'), 'my_check_cron_event' );
}
```

The difference here is strtotime() will get the correct timestamp each DAY - accounting for daylight savings, rather than simply running every 24 hours. Hope that helps someone!

Comment: Thank you for providing the answer! This is golden, you don't even need to remember to clean up the Cron jobs afterwards 